# Product Images not showing - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, product-images

I am experiencing a strange issue with Magento 2 when creating new products where the product images shows fine in the backend, it also shows on the frontend category catalog but on the actual product image gallery, it just shows the default Magento default product images.

I have tried running the `php bin/magento catalog:images:resize` command but it just makes things worse by changing all of the product images on the website to the default Magento image

- Magento 2 Version 2.3
- Permissions are set correctly in the file system

Thanks for the help in advance.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento image serves via cache. Please check cache folder permission too.

Comment: Thanks for that, that helped a lot. The permissions for the `pub/media` directory should be 775 or 777.